# why I have this error when I try to build apk of the project in flutter 'wrong Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.'?

Tags: android, flutter

I followed a tutorial to install flutter with vs code now when I try to build the project apk je encounters this error below:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\Adeol\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.96\descriptors\com.android.tools.ddms\ddmlib\27.1.0\11cd36a7dcab7d14d0c14c5e6c7582e3\descriptor.bin

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

when I created a new project in flutter I wanted to test to see if it works with the default code in main.dart but I have this error above. Of course I searched on google and YouTube I tried to modify the version of the Gradle but without hope. Can you help me please?